# Third derivative of an operator gives nan in tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I use tensorflow2.0 gpu version.

I simplified my example and try to calculate third derivative of a Gaussian correlation function.

```
def cov_mat(x1,x2):    
    res = (x1-x2)**2
    res = tf.exp(-res/2)
    return res
```

This is how I construct gradients in graph mode:

```
@tf.function
def operator(x,y):
    k = cov_mat(x, y)
    grad = tf.gradients(k,x)[0]
    grad2 = tf.gradients(grad,x)[0]
    grad3 = tf.gradients(grad2,x)[0]

    return grad, grad2, grad3
```

Now if I take sample

```
grid = np.array([[0.]]).astype('float64')
grid = tf.convert_to_tensor(grid)
grad, grad2, grad3 = operator(grid,grid)
print(grad)
print(grad2)
print(grad3)
```

It returns

```
tf.Tensor([[-0.]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor([[-1.]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor([[nan]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float64)
```

If I take different values in grid, it works well.
So, why it gives 'nan' when x=y?

Comment: It's `nan` simply because while mathematically the third derivative is 1, it does not exist in the graph. The chain is formed only up to the second derivative.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal What a pity.....